# Google Charts, Horizontal Bar chart Layout problem

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, layout, google-chat

I've implemented google charts in my angular project, all types of charts are working fine, but horizontal bar chart bars are overlaping with labels. not sure whats happening with it.

HTML

```
<div id="{{chartContainer}}" class="globalChart" [style.width.px]="chartWidth" [style.height.px]="chartHeight"></div>
```

TS

```
function drawChart() {
      const wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        containerId: tempChartId ? tempChartId : '',
        chartType: tempChartType,
        dataTable: tempChartData,
        options: {
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          seriesType: tempChartType === 'ComboChart' ? tempSeriesType : '',
          series: { 1: { type: tempChartType === 'ComboChart' ? tempSeriesType2 : '' } },
          pieHole: tempChartType === 'PieChart' && tempDonutHoleSize === 0  ? 0.88 : tempDonutHoleSize,
          pieSliceText: 'none',
          chartArea: {
            'width': tempChartAreaW ? tempChartAreaW + '%' : '80%',
            'height': tempChartAreaH ? tempChartAreaH + '%' : '70%',
            'left': tempChartType === 'PieChart' ? '' : tempYAxisSpace ? tempYAxisSpace : 50,
            'bottom': tempSpaceForLabels,
            'top': tempSpaceForLabels ? 25 : '',
          },
          areaOpacity: 0.04,
          colors: tempColors,

          bar: {
            groupWidth: tempBarWidth ? tempBarWidth : 25
          },
          candlestick: {
            fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#2c7be5' },
            risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#2c7be5' }
          },
          vAxis: {
            // textPosition:  'none',

            gridlines: {
              color: tempGridColor ? tempGridColor : '#f8f8f8',
              count: tempgradeLines ? tempgradeLines : 3
            },
            textStyle: {
              color: tempyYaxisFontColor ? tempyYaxisFontColor : '#a6adb3',
              fontSize: tempYaxisFontSize ? tempYaxisFontSize : 9,
              bold: true,
              opacity: tempyYaxisFontOpacity ? tempyYaxisFontOpacity : 0.8,
              marginTop: '50',
            },
            title: tempChartYTitle,
            titleTextStyle: {
              italic: false,
              color: tempychangeFontColorAxis ? tempychangeFontColorAxis : '#a6adb3',
              bold: false,
              fontSize: 10,
              marginBottom: 100,
            },
            ticks: tempyAixsValues,
            minValue: 0,
            format: '0'
          },

          hAxis: {
            baselineColor: '#fff',
            gridlines: {
              color: 'transparent'
          },
             textPosition:  tempHideXaxisLable ? 'none' : '',
            textStyle: {
              color: '#a6adb3',
              fontSize: 9,
              bold: true,
              opacity: 0.9,
              marginTop: '50',
            },
            title: tempChartXTitle,
            titleTextStyle: {
              italic: false,
              color: tempychangeFontColorAxis ? tempychangeFontColorAxis : '#a6adb3',
              fontSize: 10,
              bold: false,
            },
            axes: {
              x: {
                 0: {side: 'top'}
              }
           },
          },
          isStacked: tempColumnChartStack ? tempColumnChartStack : false,
          tooltip: {
            trigger: grand_parent.jeopardyGraphCheck ? 'none' : '',
            isHtml: true
          },
          // annotations: {alwaysOutside: false},
        },

      });
```

I've created common charts component for my whole project, so thats why TS file is a little bit complex.

Problem Screenshot
[image]

Normal or Expected Behaviour
[image]

Comment: Can you post the minimal code? [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise one can't reproduce your issue accurately.

Comment: I've add ```isStacked=true``` , and I solved the problem for now, may be there is any more good solution is exists. but its fixed for me me for now.
Thanks

Comment: Good to hear that. Please add this as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've add `isStacked=true` in Google chart options , and I solved the problem for now, may be there is any more good solution exists. but its fixed for me for now. Thanks :)